# I want to call the code available in first.py then wrap it inside the function. Then import that function in second.py and call

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback

I want to call the code available in first.py then wrap it inside the function. Then import that function in `second.py` and call.

`first.py`:

```
list=["ab","cd","ef"]

for i in list:
with open("input.txt", "a+") as input_file:
    print("{}".format(i), file = input_file)

Output:
ab
cd
ef
```

`second.py`:

```
input_file = open('input.txt','r')     

for line in input_file:
if "ef" in line:
   print(line)

Output:
ef
```

I want to read the text file (`input.txt`) directly from first.py script/program in second.py. Instead of calling like (`input_filt=open('input.txt,'r')`)

Answer (score 0):

The content of first.py will be

```
func_first(...):
   #do_something
```

The content of second.py will be

```
from first import func_first
func_second(...):
    func_first(...)
```

Comment: sir, please do for the above function